# Fringe movement analysis to extract displacement

Tags: laser, fourier-transform, interference, signal-processing, interferometry

I am using a Michelson interferometer with the interferogram recorded on a CMOS sensor. I have taken a video of the fringes moving when a displacement of 50 $\mu m$ is imposed to one of the mirrors.
The frame rate is 17.9980 and it is already the maximum I can have.

For a 50 $\mu m$ displacement I should see around 79 fringes passing on the sensor, as each fringe that passes corresponds to one full wavelength (632.8 nm). However, I cannot obtain clear "peaks" that allow me to identify if a fringe is moving.

In the picture you can see the frame with the fringes (top left) and the signal in the central pixel column (top right) for each frame. Then, I transformed the signals using FFT in Matlab, and I obtained the spatial frequency (always the same, so it should be correct) and the phase. Theoretically, I should be able to extract the displacement in two consecutive frames checking the phase difference, so that $$\Delta x = \frac{\lambda}{2} \frac{1}{2\pi}\Delta\phi$$
and the total displacement being the sum of the $\Delta x$ for each couple of frames.
Alternatively, I thought that I could extract the displacements looking at the integral of the signal $$\Delta S_k = S_k - S_0 $$, which is the difference between the signal at the $k$-frame and the initial signal at frame $0$. When the two signals are in phase, the integral of the difference signal should be close to zero, while when the two signals are not in phase the integral increase to a maximum when the $\Delta \phi=\pi$ (bottom right)

[image]

In the following picture there is the wrapped phase (top), unwrapped phase (centre) at the main frequency, and the integral of the difference signal at each frame (bottom). Imposing a 50 $\mu m$ in the same direction, the sign of $Delta \phi$ should be always the same, but apparently it is not. As you can see, from the difference signal the peaks are not easy to determine, there are "double peaks" and small peaks. Theoretically, I should find 79 peaks but I got more.
[image]

Is there an easier way to count fringes?
I guess that the peaks would be easier to identify if I move the mirrors more slowly?

Comment: The frequency of the fringes is always the same because if your movement is perfectly translational, then the interference pattern only moves, but the frequency is the same. I am very confused with all of this, it's hard to really understand the whole thing (too much information, in a small post). Why don't you first try to record a very slow movement and analyse the picture in an orthogonal direction to the fringes and not diagonally (about 30° from vertical in your picture), and first count the actual fringe movement (so, track a fringe across the sensor) and compare to single pixel signal.

Comment: (and btw, 50µm of movement of your mirror, should be 158 fringes as the path is doubled: 50µm one direction + 50µm back direction=100µm total beam path change)

Comment: I think you are working far too hard.  Just take the raw intensity data and set a threshold which unambiguously defines a true peak vs. noise (or smooth the data via spline functions).  Then just count the peaks.   DFTs and all that are not needed.

Comment: @JoséAndrade you're abosolutely right about the double path, my mistake.
I am using a translational mirror mount with a manual knob with 1 micron resolution, I reckon it's not easy to be accurate with manual devices. I am monitoring the differnece of intensity between signals, so for instance if I expect 158 fringe-transitions I should have 158 distinct peaks, does it make sense?

Comment: @CarlWitthoft I'm trying to count the transitions "Light-Dark-Light" to extract the displacement, not counting the fringes themselves but tracking their movement, perhaps it wasn't clear!

Comment: analyse a single pixel data, not a row first. Plot a single pixel over your movie time, do analysis from there first. slowly build it up to a second dimension later and only after you got those mastered, go on to analyse the 3 dimensional set with displacement and tilt change. I might be wrong, but I guess you also have to 0 pad your data to increase resolution in frequency space.

Comment: @Gianluca  ahh, thanks - then I'm in agreement with Jose's latest comment about starting with a single pixel; then improve the SNR by applying the same algorithm to all the pixels, with appropriate phase shifts based on position.

Comment: So, for example, if I take the central pixel in each frame and monitor the intensity it receives over the video time, I should get a signal with a number of peaks that corresponds to the fringe movement, is that correct? 
I have also tried to impose smaller displacement of 5 microns reducing the region of interest thus increasing the FPS, but I still get the same results: a lot, lot of peaks. Is the FFT not worthy? Can't I compare the phase and compute the displacements from its variations?

Comment: @JoséAndrade I guess that slowly moving the mirror by hand introduces a lot of peaks. I tried to watch the video at 0.1 speed and the movement of the fringes is not uniformly in the same direction, but they go a little bit "backward" when I'm turning the knob. I guess that if the motion would only in the "forward" direction I would have the "theoretical" number of peaks (=transitions light-dark-light), while in real life when I try to turn the knob slow I inevitably introduce some opposite components...